# Insert color into scale fill gradient at specified location / value in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill

I've created a plot in ggplot2 and then "on top" of that plot I have used `geom_rect()` to visualize (in red) the data points with the lowest 10% of values of `z`. I would still like to use `scale_fill_gradientn` to fill the legend/scale bar, but I would like to insert the color red at the minimum of the fill (i.e. that bottom of the vertical scale). How can I use `scale_fill_gradientn` and do this? Or, how can I achieve the desired result using another method?

```
# The example code here produces an plot for illustrative purposes only.
# create data frame, from ggplot2 documentation
df <- expand.grid(x = 0:5, y = 0:5) 
df$z <- runif(nrow(df))
# select min. 10%
df.1 <- df[df$z <= quantile(df$z, 0.1),]

#plot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_raster() + 
scale_fill_gradientn(colours=topo.colors(7),na.value = "transparent") +
geom_rect(data=df.1, size=1, fill="red", colour=NA , aes(xmin=x-.5, xmax=x+.5, ymin=y-.5, ymax=y+.5))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be provide `"red"` as one of the colors in `scale_fill_gradientn()`. Red is used twice to ensure that in range from 0 to 0.1 all values get "red" then with `seq()` all other values in range from 0.1001 to 1 are distributed evenly. In this case you don't need a second dataframe.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- expand.grid(x = 0:5, y = 0:5) 
df$z <- runif(nrow(df))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_raster() + 
      scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("red","red",topo.colors(6)),
                 values=c(0,0.1,seq(0.1001,1,length.out=7)),na.value = "transparent")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a smaller percentage, say 1%? For example it appears that the there needs to be at least 5% for the 'red' to show up in the scale? Can I use the minimum 1% and have the red appear with this technique?

Comment: Using this techique colors in legend are scaled according to values - so if you use 1% red color isn't visible because it takes 1/100 of whole legend.

Comment: You could transform your continous z variable into a factor in order to have a non linear scale. For instance (not tested): use     cut(z,c(0,0.1,seq(0.2,1,length.out=6)),include.lowest=T)and then use 'scale_fill_manual(values=c("red",topo.colors(6))'